# Separation of UI and game logic

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I've just created a basic Rock Paper Scissors game for a university assignment. 
I have it working very well, and it looks and behaves perfectly.

However, I've realized I've not read the requirements properly and using Visual Studio I have written all the code inside `MainWindow.xaml.cs`

Turns out, the UI should be running from `MainWindow.xaml.cs` but this should also contain an instance of `RockPaperScissorsGame.cs` class, where all the game logic should be held separate from the UI.

As it stands I have nothing in `RockPaperScissorsGame.cs` and everything in `MainWindow.xaml.cs`, which I have attached the code for below.

What's the easiest (or quickest) way for me to separate the game logic and UI?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace Rock_Paper_Scissors
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
        }

        private void Rock_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            rockButton.IsEnabled = false;
            paperButton.IsEnabled = false;
            scissorsButton.IsEnabled = false;
            newButton.IsEnabled = true;
            Random rnd = new Random();
            int ai = rnd.Next(1, 3);
            rockBG.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"green.png", UriKind.Relative));
            if (ai == 2)
            {
                resultBlock.Text = "Computer chose paper. Paper beats rock! You lose!";
                paperBG.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"yellow.png", UriKind.Relative));
                bigResult.Text = "WINNER!";
                bigResult.Foreground = Brushes.Green;
            }
            if (ai == 1)
            {
                resultBlock.Text = "Computer also chose rock. Have another go!";
                rockBG.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"orange.png", UriKind.Relative));
                bigResult.Text = "DRAW";
                bigResult.Foreground = Brushes.Orange;
            }
            if (ai == 3) {
                resultBlock.Text = "Computer chose scissors. Rock beats Scissors! You win!";
                scissorsBG.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"yellow.png", UriKind.Relative));
                bigResult.Text = "LOSER!";
                bigResult.Foreground = Brushes.Red;
            }
        }

        private void Paper_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            rockButton.IsEnabled = false;
            paperButton.IsEnabled = false;
            scissorsButton.IsEnabled = false;
            newButton.IsEnabled = true;
            Random rnd = new Random();
            int ai = rnd.Next(1, 3);
            paperBG.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"green.png", UriKind.Relative));
            if (ai == 2)
            {
                resultBlock.Text = "Computer also chose paper. Have another go!";
                paperBG.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"orange.png", UriKind.Relative));
                bigResult.Text = "DRAW";
                bigResult.Foreground = Brushes.Orange;
            }
            if (ai == 1)
            {
                resultBlock.Text = "Computer chose rock. Paper beats rock. You win!";
                rockBG.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"yellow.png", UriKind.Relative));
                bigResult.Text = "WINNER!";
                bigResult.Foreground = Brushes.Green;
            }
            if (ai == 3) {
                resultBlock.Text = "Computer chose scissors. Scissors beats paper. You lose!!";
                scissorsBG.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"yellow.png", UriKind.Relative));
                bigResult.Text = "LOSER!";
                bigResult.Foreground = Brushes.Red;
            }
        }

        private void Scissors_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            rockButton.IsEnabled = false;
            paperButton.IsEnabled = false;
            scissorsButton.IsEnabled = false;
            newButton.IsEnabled = true;
            Random rnd = new Random();
            int ai = rnd.Next(1, 3);
            scissorsBG.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"green.png", UriKind.Relative));
            if (ai == 2)
            {
                resultBlock.Text = "Computer chose paper. Scissors beats paper! You win!";
                paperBG.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"yellow.png", UriKind.Relative));
                bigResult.Text = "WINNER!";
                bigResult.Foreground = Brushes.Green;
           }
            if (ai == 1)
            {
                resultBlock.Text = "Computer chose rock. Rock beats scissors! You lose!";
                rockBG.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"yellow.png", UriKind.Relative));
                bigResult.Text = "LOSER!";
                bigResult.Foreground = Brushes.Red;

            }
            if (ai == 3) {
                resultBlock.Text = "Computer also chose scissors. Have another go!";
                scissorsBG.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"orange.png", UriKind.Relative));
                bigResult.Text = "DRAW";
                bigResult.Foreground = Brushes.Orange;
            }
        }

        private void newButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            rockButton.IsEnabled = true;
            paperButton.IsEnabled = true;
            scissorsButton.IsEnabled = true;
            newButton.IsEnabled = false;
            resultBlock.Text = "Choose Rock, Paper or Scissors to play";
            bigResult.Text = "";
            paperBG.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"blue.png", UriKind.Relative));
            rockBG.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"blue.png", UriKind.Relative));
            scissorsBG.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"blue.png", UriKind.Relative));

        }
        }
    }
```

Comment: There is no easy/quick way. You need to understand what parts of the code relate to the UI, and keep them there. All other code should go into your logic class.

Comment: You've got all of 100 lines of code there. How much time could it possibly take to rework the code? Even if you had to rewrite it from scratch, it shouldn't take that long. In any case, when you need to refactor UI and non-UI to separate, there's not really any short-cut. Just sit down and do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code contains some errors.
1. `int ai = rnd.Next(1, 3);` never chose 3, you should use `int ai = rnd.Next(1, 4);`
2. consider your naming, ai means something that has `Artificial Intelligence`, you are using just a random.

this is a very simple RPS game,

```
public class RPSMatch
{
    private static readonly Random random = new Random();

    public Result MatchResult { get; private set; }
    public Choice ComputerChoice { get; private set; }
    public Choice PlayerChoice { get; private set; }

    public enum Choice
    {
        Rock = 1,
        Paper = 2,
        Scissors = 3,
    }

    public enum Result
    {
        Lose = -1,
        Draw = 0,
        Win = 1,
    }

    public RPSMatch(Choice playerChoice)
    {
        var computerChoice = (Choice)random.Next(1, 4);
        this.PlayerChoice = playerChoice;
        this.ComputerChoice = computerChoice;
        var diff = (int)playerChoice - (int)ComputerChoice;
        this.MatchResult = (Result)(Math.Sign(diff) * (Math.Abs(diff) == 2 ? -1 : 1));
    }
}
```

use it like

```
var match = new RPSMath(RPSMatch.Rock);
```

then you can handle ui changes from `match` properties

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to use MVVM pattern and introduce view model (see this [tutorial)](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/819294/WPF-MVVM-step-by-step-Basics-to-Advance-Level)

With it the `RockPaperScissorsGame.cs` becomes a view model that contains logic to which UI layer corresponds. This mostly involves moving all methods that are under click events into public methods inside view model class together with usage of `Bindings` that enable easy connection between view and view model.